# error: could not load library ~ undefined symbol: errcontext

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos7, oracle-fdw

First, I installed oracle_fdw and oracle instant client. Second, I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME (~/.bash_profile). Finally, I ran the make command in the oracle_fdw directory. I installed the oracle_fdw extension as above, but an error occurred.

```
# login
$ su - postgres

# set system path
$ sudo vim .bash_profile
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/oracle_fdw/instantclient_11_2
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle_fdw/instantclient_11_2
export PG_CONFIG=/usr/pgsql-11/bin
PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PG_CONFIG:$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/11/data
export PGDATA

# PostgreSQL Server stop/start
$ cd /usr/pgsql-11/bin
$ ./pg_ctl stop
$ ./pg_ctl start

# make start
$ sudo make clean
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install 

# psql login
$ pgsql -p 15432

postgres=# create extension oracle_fdw;
```

The current error was that the path that the previous version was seeing as the master and the Postgresql path that the current user was looking at were different. So, I copied all the extensions and libraries to the path based on the previous version. However, the file is still created with the same old version path and the library fails to load.

As shown below, even if I tried to change the --prefix setting, the problem occurred because ./configure was not supported in oracle_fdw.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/pgsql-11
```

Can you solve this problem?

Details about your comment.

```
# oracle_fdw build
$ sudo make install
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib64/pgsql'
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/pgsql/extension'
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/pgsql/extension'
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/doc/pgsql/extension'
/bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 755  oracle_fdw.so '/usr/lib64/pgsql/oracle_fdw.so'
/bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./oracle_fdw.control '/usr/share/pgsql/extension/'
/bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./oracle_fdw--1.1.sql ./oracle_fdw--1.0--1.1.sql  '/usr/share/pgsql/extension/'
/bin/sh /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -m 644 ./README.oracle_fdw '/usr/share/doc/pgsql/extension/'

#postgreSQL version : 11.15 (before version 9.2.24)

#oracle_fdw version : 1.5.0

#postgreSQL directory : /usr/bin OR /usr/pgsql-11/bin
```

I want to install relative to /usr/pgsql-11/bin and not /usr/bin. However, the current --prefix is ​​set to /usr, so make install is not possible with the desired path.

Comment: I cannot understand this "previous version" stuff. Please show the exact messages that you get when you build oracle_fdw and the exact error from the `CREATE EXTENSION` statement. Most of all, say what version of PostgreSQL you want to build against, what version of oracle_fdw you are using and in which path PostgreSQL is installed. It would also be good to know the installation path for all other PostgreSQL versions installed on your machine.

Comment: Added content for questions. thank you.

Comment: Please always use the latest oracle_fdw version. 1.5.0 is more than 5 years old. run `make clean` to remove the old binaries. Then run `make` again and show the output you get.

Comment: (i) 11.2 is very, very old.  (ii) Unless it's temporarily  needed for a "3rd party" (i.e non Oracle) build script, don't set ORACLE_HOME when using Instant Client.

Comment: Hello Lorentz Albe, when I run make with the latest version of oracle_fdw, an error like the one in the answer below occurs.

Comment: Hello Christopher Jones, even if I use the latest version without setting ORACLE_HOME, I get the error as in the answer below.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: It has been upgraded from version 9.2.24 to version 11, and it seems that the master continues to exist as version 9.2.24.

Answer (score 0):

oracle_fdw version : 2.4.0

If you run make using the latest version of oracle_fdw, the following error occurs.

```
$ sudo make clean
$ sudo make
gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -DLINUX_OOM_SCORE_ADJ=0 -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -fPIC -I"/sdk/include" -I"/oci/include" -I"/rdbms/public" -I"/" -I/usr/include/oracle/21/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/19.12/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/19.12/client -I/usr/include/oracle/19.11/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/19.11/client -I/usr/include/oracle/19.10/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/19.10/client -I/usr/include/oracle/19.9/client -I/usr/include/oracle/19.9/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/19.8/client -I/usr/include/oracle/19.8/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/19.6/client -I/usr/include/oracle/19.6/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/19.3/client -I/usr/include/oracle/19.3/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/18.5/client -I/usr/include/oracle/18.5/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/18.3/client -I/usr/include/oracle/18.3/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client -I/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client -I/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client -I/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.4/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.4/client64 -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.3/client -I/usr/include/oracle/10.2.0.3/client64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/pgsql/server -I/usr/include/pgsql/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o oracle_fdw.o oracle_fdw.c
oracle_fdw.c:11:33: fatal error: access/htup_details.h: No such file or directory
 #include "access/htup_details.h"
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [oracle_fdw.o] Error 1
```

Since the default prefix value is /usr, if you want to change the installation path, you need to change the prefix value.

If I solve the current path problem, it seems to work fine, but even if I try to change the --prefix value, I can't find a file that can be changed.